# custom menu/sub-menu output

Tags: routes, theming

what would i have to do to change the menu output structure for my theme?

this is the current structure:

```
<ul class="menu">                                //menu
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Other Stuff</a>
    <ul class="menu">                            // sub-menu
      <li><a href="">Sub-Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Page 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

what i would like to get is something like that:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="drop">Other Stuff</a>  // the 'drop' class is for the styling of a menu item with child-items
        <div class="dropdown_1column">
            <div class="col_1">
            <a href="">Sub-Page 1</a>
            <a href="">Sub-Page 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: did you get the solution? If yes then can you post the solution as an answer please..

Answer (score 1):

Do you know of the [nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module?  Nice menus will allow you to make dropdown menus without writing any code on your own.  You can also find instructions for customizing the Nice menus CSS [here](http://drupal.org/node/185543).

Nice menus has almost 60,000 installs as of this writing, indicating that it is likely to be supported well into the future compared to modules that aren't so popular.

Comment: mhh... not quite what i was looking for. i tried it out but i saw no option to configure the output markup to my needs. also i wanted to use my own menu css styles that i already have

Comment: What needs do you have that you weren't able to satisfy?

Comment: there's one thing that i don't need and one thing that i can't do with the plugin. i don't need the nice menu css styles because i want to use my own styles that fit into my layout and not the predefined stuff.
the thing i couldn't do (or at least i didn't find it) with the moduel is customizing the output markup so that i get the structure that i described above. and when i have the module and still have to modify my template files then i'm better off without the module because it doesn't add any useful functionality for me.

Comment: but in the meantime i have the solution for my problem (80% finished). as soon as i got it running 100% i will describe the steps i took to adjust the menu output structure to my needs.